# Data Inquiry: Collections of common objects with attributes

Tags: data-request

Does anybody know if there is any publicly available collection of common objects, animals, events, and things which lists categorical attributes?

Such a database might look the following (if inefficiently organized):

```
object  aquatic bird mammal domesticated man-made made-of-wood
dog     0       0    1      1            0        0 
door    0       0    0      0            1        1
ostrich 0       1    0      0            0        0
```

I have been playing around with [`ConceptNet5`](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/) for a few days now but don't feel that it is consistently accurate enough for my needs. I would rather have a smaller database which has been constructed by hand if possible.

Comment: Have you seen the Wikipedia page on Commonsense knowledge (artificial intelligence)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonsense_knowledge_(artificial_intelligence)  It includes ConceptNet5 and several other similar projects.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to use this for, and why specifically "objects", animals, events and "things" (and what the difference is between "object" and "thing")? This question seems very broad.

Comment: Is there something wrong with a response being broad?